# Solidity Acces public varialbles ethers.js

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js

I am trying to fetch data on public variables from the blockchain using ethers.js.
but other declared functions will work properly.
This is the way I am using it.
My solidity:

```
contract NLTNFT is ERC1155, Ownable {

    uint256[] public tiers;
    uint256 public maxPerWallet;

    constructor() ERC1155('https://nlt.rocks/metadata/{id}.json'){
    tiers = [0, 1, 2];
    maxPerWallet = 3;
    }
}
```

My JS ethers.js:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(nltContractAddress, NLTNFT.abi, signer);
//then
const res = await contract.tiers(1);
// or
const res2 = await contract.maxPerWallet();
```

in both case this is what I get:

```
err: Error: call revert exception (method="tiers(uint256)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.2.0)
    at Logger.makeError (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:59669)
    at Logger.throwError (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:59874)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:206132)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:311725)
    at step (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:305047)
    at Object.next (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:304307)
    at fulfilled (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:303681)
```

here is a remix screenshot
all the orange feature I can get from JS all the blue I can't
[image]

Comment: the call exception might be because you're trying to access an element of the array which is out of bounds? I.e. have you "pushed" entries to the array?

Comment: thanks for your reply,    and yes it's filled at initialization.

Comment: no @ruby_newbie , tiers is an array but as it is declared as public, it automatically creates a getter so that there is a function basically doing that:

`function tiers(uint256 index) public view returns (uint256) { return thiers[index]; }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by wrong RPC url, you should consider this case.